# Incrementing a Razor Variable in JavaScript isn't Working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I tried doing an allocation page in which if you wish to add extra person, you must click the "add one more" button. I had a count variable and first time when I clicked the button and called the function, things worked well, but when I click the button second time I realized that the previous increment of count isn't getting reflected. How should I make the increment permanent or any other solution using which I can achieve this.

```
@{
    int count = 1;
}
<script>
function AddNewDoc(ElementId) {
//This Increment is not reflected when the function is called again
@{
count++;
}

document.getElementById(ElementId).innerHTML = "<td>A</td>" + "<td>B</td>" + "    <td>C</td>" + "<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Add One More Doctor\"      onclick=\"AddNewDoc(@count)\" /></td></tr>" + "<tr id=\"@count\">";
 }
</script>
@Html.ActionLink("GO BACK TO OPD POSTING", "UnitAndMonth", "OPD")
    <br />

    <br />
    <h2>@ViewBag.msg</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "OPD", FormMethod.Post))
    {  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[count].dr_name, new { @class = "input1", @id = "tags" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[count].from_date, new { @class = "input1", @id = "datepicker" + count, @readonly = "readonly" })
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[count].to_date, new { @class = "input1", @id = "datepicker" + count + count, @readonly = "readonly" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Add One More Doctor" onclick="AddNewDoc(@count)" />
        </td>

    </tr>
      <tr id="@count"></tr>

    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.

Comment: Javascript cannot call server side code like that. The serverside code will only be run on load of the page. Is there a reason you dont want to store the value of that code in a javascript variable or in a HiddenField?

Comment: No, there isn't any reason. But how do I use the javascript variable inside my "@Html.TextBoxFor" tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you count will always be 2 in the code above. You should also reconsider

```
    <tr id="count"></tr>
```

because id's should be more descriptive than just being an integer.

try getting rid of all the @count, something like:

```
    <script>

    var count = 1;
    function AddNewDoc(ElementId) {
            count = count+1;
            document.getElementById(ElementId).innerHTML = "<td>A</td>" + "<td>B</td>" + "    <td>C</td>" + "<td><input         type=\"button\" value=\"Add One More Doctor\"      onclick=\"AddNewDoc(count)\" /></td></tr>" + "<tr id=\"count\">";
     }

     </script>

     <input type="button" value="Add One More Doctor" onclick="AddNewDoc(count)" />
```